# TortoiseSVN through a proxy

Tags: windows-7, svn, isa-server

I'm trying to set up my Win7 work laptop so I can access my svn repos. My repository is set up on a Linux box at home and works fine from all of the my machines, including my work laptop when I'm not connected to the work network.

The problem comes when I try to access through the proxy - I've added the proxy settings in the TortoiseSVN settings panel, when I try to check out a project, it starts downloading and runs for about 6.5MB before giving up and complaining that the remote connection was closed. The repository I'm testing with only has a single text file in it, it's nowhere near 6MB. From what I can work out in my router logs, the requests from work weren't getting through, so I don't know what it was downloading!

It appears there is an issue with the web proxy at work, I'm just wondering if there is anything I can do about it? It's a Microsoft ISA server, and I don't have much control over its configuration, so I'm really hoping there is a solution, I'm just not sure where to start.

Edit: I can browse the repository via HTTP through my work proxy just fine, just can't seem to do anything using svn. I also tried installing SVN proper and doing it from a DOS command line, that didn't work at all, I got the remote connection closed error after just a few seconds and no downloading of phantom giant files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about working this issue around by setting up https server at home?

isa is not [finjan](http://www.finjan.com/).. it should just forward the traffic without interfering with actual communication.

Comment: Any ISA would inspect http traffic at the very least unless specifically told not to, and could very well inflict problems on it depending on the content and the patch level, version and configuration of the ISA server...

Comment: @Oskar Duveborn - right, but it will not inspect HTTPS, just forward it without running man-in-the-middle attack on it.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've configured it all to work via https, everything works fine at home (except for all the complaints about it not being a real certificate, subject of another question at another time I think), I'll try it out at work tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: @MalphasWats sure thing.. please let us know how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm, it hadn't occurred to me to try https yet, I wanted to make sure I could access everything before I bothered putting passwords on and making it all secure, now it's all done! Seems fixing the annoying "Certificate Error" thing will cost money, so I'll just click the "I don't care" button instead :) Thanks again.

Comment: @MalphasWats for 10$/yr you can get a valid ssl cert, it all depends what security level you need. also.... another solution would be to run ssh at port 443 at home and use isa proxy to tunnel ssh traffic via putty [ putty can use http proxy server to forward it's traffic ] and in turn to tunnel svn over ssh over http.... yet another way of braking it-policy of your employer ;-]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your repo is accessible via HTTP try browsing to your repo from a web browser and see what you get.  It could be that the proxy is asking for authentication that Tortoise isn't sending it.

If you don't have it set up to be accessed via HTTP then you'll want to do that in order to get to it from behind your proxy.

Comment: Thanks, I can indeed access the repo via my web browser through the proxy

Comment: It could be that the proxy is just eating it.  I believe Tortoise uses WebDAV which has special requirements in ISA.  Do you know what version of ISA the proxy is using?

Comment: it's ISA 2006 according to the login pages, which *should* allow WebDAV as far as I understand.